# C# AES encrypt with CFB NoPadding Mode in Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

i encrypt data with AES/CFB/NoPadding algorithm in c# , but i can't decrypt with same mode in java .. I got the different result .

CFB-NoPadding mode allows any bytes data in and same length data out .

i can do that in using CBC padding mode ..but it doesn't work in CFB no padding mode .

Can anyone help me ?

C# encrypt Code:

```
_assistantRM.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
_assistantRM.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
_assistantRM.FeedbackSize = 8;
_assistantRM.IV = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF }; 
_assistantRM.Key = _assitantKey;
```

Java Decrypt Code:

```
SecretKeySpec sk = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk, new byte[] { 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF });
byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
return result;
```

Comment: 8 bits for the feedback size in c# seems to be very small. The common CFB mode uses AFAIR one cipher block which means 128 bit for AES.

Comment: But CBF nopadding mode is just allowed to use 8 bit FeedbackSize .. has any other mode to  achieve isometric encrypt with more efficient and strong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little known switch in the algorithm string in Java. Try `"AES/CFB8/NoPadding"` (note the 8-character behind the B) instead. It configures the amount of bits used as feedback from the encrypted block.

Note that usually the error recovery of CFB is not used much anymore. It is much more efficient to use the full 128 bits of feedback. Or you could use another mode entirely, such as CTR or GCM mode encryption.

Comment: another question is i want use same length encrypt method . that means input x bytes and output x bytes . so , just cbf nopadding mode can do that . other algorithms will change my input data length to fixed 16 or 32 bytes  . any other recommend ? :P , Thanks again~~

Comment: That's trickier because of the IV value (which is also required for CFB to be fully secure). Otherwise only ECB and CBC pad the data. CTR and OFB don't require padding either and CBC can be used with ciphertext stealing. It depends on the problem if that question can be solved easily, in the worst case you need Format Preserving Encryption. CTR is pretty popular but CTR certainly requires a unique IV.